# setting up vim with latex suite

Tags: 12.04, vim, latex

I am trying to setup vim with latex suite.  I have installed vim from the terminal prompt

```
sudo apt-get install vim
```

but

```
sudo apt-get install latex-suite or latexsuite
```

doesn't do anything.  What do I do to install the latex-suite?  After that, what else needs to be done to get vim going with the suite?  I have seen the vim website but the instructions weren't helpful to me since I am new to Linux.

Comment: Could you enter twice the apt command, copy **all** the output an add it here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Searching a bit on Internet I found that the package is called `vim-latexsuite` instead of just `latexsuite` or `latex-suite`.

So to install it enter the following command in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install vim-latexsuite
```

Once you've installed it, just open a TeX file in Vim. No other setup is required.

Comment: that helped.  Do you know how to set up vim and the latex suite by any chance?

Comment: What do you mean by any chance? Do you want to know how to configure it?

Comment: Dan Hulme added that nothing else needs to be done.  Do you know how I can open a file located in my documents folder in vim?  Is is :e /Documents/filename?

Comment: @dustin Yes `:e` is used for opening files.  However, you might need to use `~/Documents/filename` instead of `/Documents/filename`.

Comment: @dustin Remember that if you have a *new question*, you should [create it](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) in a separately post. Thanks!